# In MySQL if a field has no data should it be empty or null, or other?

Tags: mysql, database-design, field

I'm putting together a MySQL database and the data is a list of customers. Not all of the fields for each customer has data. So some fields are empty. We hope to complete the missing data, but would like to be able to produce a report using SELECT to list those customer records which have missing data fields.

What should be stored in those fields until data can be updated to them? Should it be NULL? Empty? Or something else? Also, when setting up the MySQL TABLE what should the NULL column be set to and what should the DEFAULT column be set to to best handle those situations where there might not be data? Thanks!

Comment: if name is empty then insert as name = ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` explicitly means *no data*.

So if you want to make sure that you mean *it has no value*, use `NULL`. Otherwise, all other defaults are considered values.

A blank string `''` is a value.
Zero `0` is also a value.

But `NULL` is special as it means *no value*.

It will make querying rows where *nothing is entered* easier.

You should still do type-checking for your data - so that people don't enter `-1` or `0` in a height or weight column. For us, its obvious - nothing can have `0` height, but to a database the column has a value - even if its *illogical* and you'll have to adjust your queries to filter these rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to `NULL` as it is the standard value to represent the `UNKNOWN` or missing values in [the three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

Comment: But keep in mind that three valued logic is confusing and illogical, if you are used to two valued logic.  You would figure that the count of all rows that have X=3 and the count of all rows that have X!=3 would add up  to the count of all rows.  But no. The rows where X is NULL don't go into either count.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you'll want to allow null for things like this. Talking specifically about strings; one day, the empty string may be a valid value. Likewise with a numeric field, if you do not allow nulls, you then have to resort to using a special value to mean "empty", like -9876.6789 which is never fun to code around.

Just remember that when writing a query and looking for nulls, you will likely get misleading results if you do something like `field != null`. You'll want to use `field is not null`.

Hope that helps!